# AWS CodeCommit buildspec, is it possible to use an environmental variable for a secrets manager key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, buildspec

In my buildspec.yaml, I want to use an environmental variable, for example, "$ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", for a key of secrets manager. Also, I want to convert a value of the environment variable to upper case.

I tried the following, but it says

> [Container] 2023/06/28 07:14:34 Phase context status code: Secrets
> Manager Error Message: ValidationException: Invalid name. Must be a
> valid name containing alphanumeric characters, or any of the
> following: -/_+=.@!

```
env:
  secrets-manager:
    VAR_NAME: "SOMEHING_${ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT^^}:VAR_NAME"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using env variables works in buildspec. I guess that your issue is with ^^ signs that you put... Also, for me it works without quote signs, like this  DB_PORT: ${DB_ENV_NAME}/db_access:port

Comment: I ended up using a plain text string instead of an env param. Anyway, thank you for your comment.